# Analysis of differentiability after addition of complex valued functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

It's given that $f(z)=g(z)+h(z)$, where $f,g,h$ are complex valued functions of a complex variable z.

My questions are:

1. If $g,h$ are differentiable at $z_{0}$, does that necessarily make $f$ differentiable at $z_{0}$ ?
2. Is the converse of my previous question true  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $z_0$, $f \equiv g + h$ is differentiable at $z_0$ since
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\frac{g(z)-g(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}+\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\frac{h(z)-h(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}=g^{\prime}(z)+h^{\prime}(z).
$$

The converse is not true.
Consider a function $g$ which is nondifferentiable at $z_0$, and let $h=-g$. Then, $f\equiv g+h=0$, which is clearly differentiable everywhere.

Note also that this does not have much to do with complex numbers.

Comment: Take $g(z) = \bar{z}$ for an easy example.

Comment: parsiad and @copper.hat Nice examples. Thank you both.

Comment: A side question - the function formed (after addition)  by the example given by @copper.hat is not analytic because it doesn't satisfy C.R equations. Why is that ? How different is "differentiability" from "being analytic" in this particular example. If the answer is too much off the topic, can you point me to the right references ?

Comment: Differentiable just means differentiable at a point, analytic means being differentiable in a neighbourhood of a point. For example, $f(z) = |z|^2$ is differentiable at zero but is not analytic.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks a lot. Those examples really help a lot, as,  definitions are present everywhere without proper examples.